# building of gradle not finished androidstudio-ubuntu(14.04 -32bit)

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I have 32bit ubuntu14.04LTS i installed android studio2.1.3 from android developer site when i try to run a project it takes much time for gradle to build it shows error as

/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt: 2: /home/usr/Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

default aapt binary from the distribution are 64 bit only, distribution for api 23 from google was the last one to support 32 bit aapt and build-tools etc.
fix: download api 23 and overwrite the binary files. It may break some stuff in the future, and if android decides to update you have to do it again..